Defining Markers and colors from spreadsheet column entry?
I working on a  a 3D scatter plot for RGB analysis, which is getting data points from .xlsx[enter . I have placed listed possible markers and colors as:
markers = ["." , "," , "o" , "v" , "^" , "<", ">",]
colors = ['r','g','b','c','m', 'y', 'k']
sheet 1
I cannot discover the correct code to pull marker and color for each data point.
I tried adding the marker and color columns in this line:
from this (generrates graph fine)
ax.scatter3D(df['R'], df['G'], df['B'], alpha = 0.5)
to this:
fg = ax.scatter3D(df['R'], df['G'], df['B'], df['M'], markers = 'M', df['C'], colors = 'C',. alpha = 0.5)
whish generates empty graph and I get " Syntac
but it generates this:
fg = ax.scatter3D(df['R'], df['G'], df['B'], df['M'], markers = 'M', df['C'], colors = 'C', alpha = 0.5)
                                                                                                            ^

SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
the ^ symbol is under the close parenthesis
here is my code:
import seaborn as sns


import pandas as pd
import ezodf


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

markers = ["." , "," , "o" , "v" , "^" , "<", ">",]
colors = ['r','g','b','c','m', 'y', 'k']


sns.set_style("whitegrid", {'axes.grid' : False})


df = pd.read_excel ('/Users/stanbrown/Desktop/Plot 3D/RGB plots 1.xlsx')

print(df.head)
print(df.columns)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
fg = ax.scatter3D(df['R'], df['G'], df['B'], alpha = 0.5)


ax.set_xlabel('Red')
ax.set_ylabel('Green')
ax.set_zlabel('Blue')


plt.show()


The error you're getting, "SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument", is because you're mixing up how you provide arguments to the scatter3D function.
In your code, df['M'] and df['C'] are being interpreted as positional arguments, but they come after the keyword argument markers='M', which isn't allowed in python.
Here's how to fix your code to correctly use the marker and color columns from your DataFrame by using a loop, since matplotlib expects a single marker style for all points when you use the marker argument:
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_style("whitegrid", {'axes.grid' : False})

df = pd.read_excel('/Users/stanbrown/Desktop/Plot 3D/RGB plots 1.xlsx')
print(df.head)
print(df.columns)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

for i in range(len(df)):
    ax.scatter3D(df['R'][i], df['G'][i], df['B'][i], 
                 marker=df['M'][i], c=df['C'][i], alpha=0.5)

ax.set_xlabel('Red')
ax.set_ylabel('Green')
ax.set_zlabel('Blue')

plt.show()

What should be shown:


I have followed your suggestion with the exception of inserting-ax.set_xlim(left=0)
(0.0, 1.0)
ax.set_ylim(0.0, 1.0)
ax.set_zlim(bottom=0)
(0.0, 1.0)
